# push() dispatches LOCATION_CHANGE action even if I push the same url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I'm using built-in react-router-redux `push()` action-creator to navigate routes in my application. It dispatches `LOCATION_CHANGE` action even when I push the same URL as the previous.

Is it default behavior? And if it is, can I change it somehow without writing additional middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `dispatch` an action from action-creater you usually expect an action being dispatched. So yes it is a default behaviour.

You can take a look at actions implementation [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/blob/master/src/actions.js)

You can check your location before dispatching action like this:

```
import { history } from './app.js'; // file where you export history instance

const location = history.getCurrentLocation();
```